# I need data from Prior Monday to saturday when i run my interface on Tuesday at 1:30am. utlized a example query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
from VP_TIMESHTPUNCHV42
where  (EVENTDATE>=getdate()-8) AND (EVENTDATE <=getdate()-3)
AND PERSONNUM = '668795'
```

so it should -9 or -8 here? please help me understand about the dates and what dates will be included here ?
If my Tuesday is 15th Oct and the previous Sat is 12thoct and mon is 7thoct
I need data from Mon7th oct to sat12th oct

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from Monday to Saturday. `WeekDay` is from 2(Monday) to 7(Saturday)

```
select *
from VP_TIMESHTPUNCHV42
where datepart(weekday, EVENTDATE) between 2 and 7 AND PERSONNUM = '668795'
```

**or** (if only within this week)

```
select *
from VP_TIMESHTPUNCHV42
where EVENTDATE between getdate() - 1 and getdate() + 5 AND PERSONNUM = '668795' 

select *
from VP_TIMESHTPUNCHV42
where EVENTDATE between dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and dateadd(day, 5, cast(getdate() as date)) 
and PERSONNUM = '668795'
```

Comment: Monday and sat also should be included ... will ur logic work ?

Comment: if today is tuesday, then getdate() - 1 is monday, getdate() + 5 is saturday

Comment: i added dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) to ignore the time.